# When connenting to Wifi with Netgear WNA3001m USB dongle whole Ubuntu 16.04 crashes

Tags: networking, wireless, usb

Whenever I try to connect to wifi (with my USB dongle Netgear WNA3100M) Ubuntu freezes. There is no problem with plugging in the USB dongle. I can even see what networks are available. If I try to connect with a wrong password it still works (but offcourse tells me that the password is wrong) but as soon as I try to connect with the proper password Ubuntu freezes immediately.

This is happening since I updated to a newer kernel version.

When I boot into an older kernel (4.4.0-62) everything works fine.

Output of lsb_release -a:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

Ouput of uname -a

```
Linux MyPCName 4.4.0-66-generic #87-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 3 15:29:05 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Output of sudo lshw -class network

```
*-network               
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
   logical name: enp3s0
   version: 06
   serial: 00:25:22:d9:35:b0
   size: 10Mbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8168e-3_0.0.4 03/27/12 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
   resources: irq:36 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:d0004000-d0004fff memory:d0000000-d0003fff
*-network
   description: Wireless interface
   physical id: 1
   bus info: usb@2:5
   logical name: wlxa42b8c5e383e
   serial: a4:2b:8c:5e:38:3e
   capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8192cu driverversion=4.4.0-66-generic firmware=N/A link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
```

output of lsusb

```
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0846:9021 NetGear, Inc. WNA3100M(v1) Wireless-N 300 [Realtek RTL8192CU]
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:0841 Logitech, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 009 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 003: ID 145f:0176 Trust Isla Keyboard
Bus 008 Device 002: ID 046d:c03e Logitech, Inc. Premium Optical Wheel Mouse (M-BT58)
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Output of lspci

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 12h Processor Root Complex
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] BeaverCreek [Radeon HD 6550D]
00:01.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] BeaverCreek HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 6500D and 6400G-6600G series]
00:10.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB XHCI Controller (rev 03)
00:10.1 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB XHCI Controller (rev 03)
00:11.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [IDE mode] (rev 40)
00:12.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB OHCI Controller (rev 11)
00:12.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB EHCI Controller (rev 11)
00:13.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB OHCI Controller (rev 11)
00:13.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB EHCI Controller (rev 11)
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 13)
00:14.1 IDE interface: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH IDE Controller
00:14.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH Azalia Controller (rev 01)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 11)
00:14.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH PCI Bridge (rev 40)
00:14.5 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB OHCI Controller (rev 11)
00:15.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Hudson PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 0)
00:15.3 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Hudson PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 3)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 0 (rev 43)
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 1
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 2
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 3
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 4
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 6
00:18.6 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 5
00:18.7 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 7
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 06)
```

Output of rfkill list all

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
```

Output of lsmod | grep rtl

```
rtl8192cu              69632  0
rtl_usb                20480  1 rtl8192cu
rtl8192c_common        53248  1 rtl8192cu
rtlwifi                77824  3 rtl_usb,rtl8192c_common,rtl8192cu
mac80211              737280  3 rtl_usb,rtlwifi,rtl8192cu
cfg80211              565248  2 mac80211,rtlwifi
```

Output of dpkg -l network-manager

```
||/ Naam                                          Versie                      Architectuur                Omschrijving
+++-=============================================-===========================-===========================-===============================================================================================
ii  network-manager                               1.2.6-0ubuntu0.16.04.1      amd64                       network management framework (daemon and userspace tools)
```

By the way, all output was generated with my usb-dongle inserted, but not connected to the Wifi-network.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NetGear WNA3100M Wireless adaptor (RTL8192CU) crashes Ubuntu 16.10 after update to latest kernel (4.8.0-41)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/890936/netgear-wna3100m-wireless-adaptor-rtl8192cu-crashes-ubuntu-16-10-after-update)

Comment: Welcome to Askubuntu! Please help us help you by [edit]ing the output of `lsb_release -a` and `uname -a` into your post. Thank you!

Comment: @ElderGeek Added the output of both lsb_release and uname. CelticWarrior Might indeed be a duplicate, allthough I only have the freeze when I connect to an wifi-network. Since that thread seems to be abandond by the original asker I like to go ahead with this one.

Comment: @CelticWarrior called duplicate may or may not apply. It's difficult to say without the output of  `lsmod | grep rtl` Be that as it may, Please provide details about your wireless card obtained from your system as outlined in [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into/61547#61547) Thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: @ElderGeek thanks for helping me so far. I edited the rest of the information you asked for. I didn't add dmesg, because that would add several extra pages of code.

Comment: Your welcome. I'd still like to see  the output of `lsmod | grep rtl` edited into your post as well. Thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: @ElderGeek edited the post gaan. Hope this helps.

Comment: Do you get the same result regardless of the USB port that you use?  I know that you state that this happened when you upgraded the kernel, but can you confirm that [booting a previous kernel](http://askubuntu.com/questions/82140/how-can-i-boot-with-an-older-kernel-version) resolves the issue?

Comment: @ElderGeek Yes, right now I am in the previous kernel (4.4.0-62) and the wifi works fine.

Comment: This sounds very much like a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1671611) that appeared beginning with kernel 4.4.0-63 that's been charged against Network Manager. Please [edit] the output of  `dpkg -l network-manager` into your post.

Comment: @eldergeek so it might be in the network-manager? I edited the question with the information. Thanks for the continuing help.

Comment: It looks that way, however charges don't always equate to guilt. Be that as it may, I recommend that you subscribe to [this bug] so that the devs can be aware of the impact and you can be notified of any workarounds and when the bug is squashed. It's been reported that you can workaround this problem [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1671611/comments/26) by issuing the command `sudo service network-manager restart` or by downgrading network-manager to v.1.2.2. Unfortunately I can neither confirm nor deny at present.

Comment: My apologies. I meant to say this bug. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1671611

Comment: @eldergeek, okay thanks for your help. I will subscribe to the bug and hope it will be squashed soon :-)

Answer (score 0):

For a while the solution was booting into the older kernel. But since kernel update 4.4.0-75-generic everything is working again.

So the current solution is updating the kernel to the latest version.

Comment: After a bit more delving into the changes in the new kernel version, found that this bug (which was squashed) was the cause of the problem: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1666421